# iOS addView: Adds view from story board without constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, addsubview

I have a View in the Storyboard, which shows an error message. I remove this at load using

```
[self.ErrorView removeFromSuperView];
```

Later on in the code, I then want to show the view, using

```
[self.MainView addSubview:self.ErrorView];
```

this does show the view, but the view is only sized by the content within in, where as on the story board it is size to full width using the 'Leading/Trailing Edge' constraints.

How do I refresh the view's constraints to match those on the storyboard.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617991/what-happens-with-constraints-when-a-view-is-removed) may help explain what happens and what to do. When you remove a view, the constraints are removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to only show and hide view in `UIViewController`? If that is your purpose you should use this code:

```
self.ErrorView.hidden = YES;  // To hide alert
```

and

```
self.ErrorView.hidden = NO;  // To show alert
```

Comment: i do want to hide the view, but i need the rest of the screen to readjust for it not being there, it is not an overlay

Comment: this way works perfectly, not sure why i thought to remove the view. much easier. many thanks

Comment: Cool, the simplest solution are the best - always :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a strong private property outlets to those two constraints. 
When you need to re-add the view to the view hierarchy again, you just add those two constraints back into the hierarchy using the addConstraint method.

```
    [self.parentView addConstraint:self.constraintX];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take all constraints using `[self.ErrorView constraints];` then loop through it and find the constraint that has ErrorView as one of the item that it constraints on and then add that constraint to the ErrorView using

```
[self.ErrorView addConstraint: retrievedConstrainted];
```