# How to preserve NSLayoutConstraints when rearranging hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

I made a custom UIView and made the UI with an XIB and the hierarchy is like below

[image]

The highlighted view has many constraints hooked with its superview. Now I want to make the view the subview of the vibrancy effect view, AND preserve the constraints between the `highlighted view` and the `current superview`.

Right now if I just drag the view inside, the constraints are removed.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you have to recreate the constraints, since they are relative to the View>Superview relationship. Sorry.

Comment: This is the current behaviour, there's little you can do about it: : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617991/what-happens-with-constraints-when-a-view-is-removed

Comment: I guess so... thanks guys